# Read all files from all the folders

Tags: python, file, opencv, video, mediapipe

I am using Windows, Jupyter Notebook, OpenCV, Mediapipe, Tensorflow.

Hello. I have a video Dataset with 100 action folders and each folder has 100 videos(.avi). Frames Per Second is 25. I want to read all the videos in all the action folders to collect the keypoints.

I just want help with the code reading all the videos from all the folders using for loop or anything. And is there anyway to check if that code indeed read all the videos from all the folders?

Please review the below code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C://Users/User/Body_gesture/DATA')
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    
    for action in actions:
        for sequence in range(no_sequences):
            for frame_num in range(sequence_length):
                
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                
                image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
                draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)
                
                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

1st. I don't know the format on how to provide the Dataset path. There seems to be infinite number of ways to do that when I searched online.

2nd. I am trying to pass the Dataset folder in cv2.VideoCapture. And I want to read all the videos from all the action folders so that I can get the keypoints.

Comment: doesn't work like that. VideoCapture will read one video file you specify. what you do there looks wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah I thought so too. Could you please suggest a solution for this? I have been stuck on this for a long time. Please help.

Comment: so use python builtin functions (pathlib module) to list your directories and get the video file names, then open them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using Python. Here is an example that you can use to create your own function.

```
def list_all_files_with_an_extension(pth_folder: str, ends_with: str = None, starts_with: str=None) -> list:
"""
List all files with an extension in a folder
:param pth_folder: Path to the directory to look for the files
:param ends_with: File extension. The file should end with this extension.
:return: List of all files in the folder and its subfolders
"""
# Adjust to the list
if isinstance(ends_with, str):
    ends_with = [ends_with]
# Adjust to the list
if isinstance(starts_with, str):
    starts_with = [starts_with]
# Placeholder
list_files = []
# Walk through dir and sub dir
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pth_folder):
    for file in files:
        if all(
                [any([file.endswith(_ext) for _ext in ends_with]),
                 any([file.startswith(_start) for _start in starts_with])]
        ):

            list_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
# Return the list of paths
return list_files
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. This helps so much. So let me put it this way. I do exactly what you said and get all the video files in "list_all_files_with_an_extension" function. Then I will assign that to "all_files = list_all_files_with_an_extension". Then I'll pass "all_files" as argument in VideoCapture  ---->>  cv2.VideoCapture(all_files). So will this read all the video files right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'cv2.VideoCapture' function. If the function accepts a list of paths, you could pass the entire list of files. Else, you have to use some form of vectorization or a for loop to process each file separately.

Comment: What I am exactly trying to do is, read all the videos from all the folders, collect the keypoints from all the frames in the videos using Mediapipe. Then creating another Dataset folder where I will save those keypoints as numpy arrays. That will be same as the original dataset folder. It will also contain all 100 action folders/Each video will be in the form of a folder/in this folder, all the frames which are converted into numpy arrays are stored.